# Tax class "Zero rate" per user role on specific product ID's

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I got this code that will apply tax free on a user role regardless of what they order, which is fine.

But now I need another user role that will apply tax free **on specific products id**, and I'm not sure how to acomplish that.

The code im using right now for tax free on all products for specific user role is:

```
// Apply a different tax rate based on the user role.

function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {
// Getting the current user 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_data = get_userdata($current_user->ID);

if ( in_array( 'administrator', $current_user_data->roles ) || in_array( 'userrolename', $current_user_data->roles ) )
    $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';

return $tax_class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );
// Fin Apply a different tax rate based on the user role.
```

Comment: yes, i need just one (or two) user role to be able to get free tax on specific product id's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that will apply this "Zero Rate" tax class for some defined products and some defined user roles:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );
function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Define HERE your targeted products IDs
    $products_ids_arr = array(12 ,15, 24);

    // Define HERE your targeted user roles
    $users_role_arr = array('administrator', 'userrolename');

    //Getting the current user data
    $user_data = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());

    foreach ($users_role_arr as $user_role)
        if ( in_array( $user_role, $user_data->roles ) && in_array( $cart_item->id, $products_ids_arr ) ) {
            $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';
            break;
        }

    return $tax_class;

}
```

This code is tested and works.

*Code goes in any php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin php files.*

Comment: You are awesome man, i havent tested it yet, but i will do asap and let you know!

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a few different projects, and I got a few doubts about lots of things, that is why, but I will post the results soon, thanks a lot once more

Answer (score 0):

**CASE 1** Via code

You can use `add role` function like

```
<?php add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities ); ?>
```

Example

```
add_role('basic_contributor', 'Basic Contributor', array(
    'read' => true, // True allows that capability
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
));
```

**CASE 2 :** Via Plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info, but you seem to do not understand my question. I know how to create roles, but what i need is a specific user role to have tax free on a specific product id.

Comment: No, as it does apply the tax for all the products, not to one and only product ID (or at least not as far as i understand the code) would you point at me where in my code is the filter for the product ID?

Comment: you have product object.

Comment: I copied that code from another thread, but i dont know about php code at all... i understand i got $product, but I dont know what should i add or modify on my code to apply JUST on certain product id's. Please please help me, I would very much appreciate if you can modify it, that way i might see the difference and understand the code completely