# Set "Zero Tax" rate to a some custom booking product types

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, tax

With WooCommerce, I am using [Traveler](https://themeforest.net/item/traveler-traveltourbooking-wordpress-theme/10822683) premium theme

I need to deactivate (TAX) in the tours and hotels, And I am trying to use this code for it:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $cart_item ) {

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

// Define HERE your targeted products IDs
$products_ids_arr = array(12 ,15, 24);

// Define HERE your targeted user roles
$users_role_arr = array('administrator', 'userrolename');

//Getting the current user data
$user_data = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());

foreach ($users_role_arr as $user_role)
    if ( in_array( $user_role, $user_data->roles ) && in_array( $cart_item->id, $products_ids_arr ) ) {
        $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';
        break;
    }

return $tax_class;}
```

*This code come from this answer: [Tax class "Zero rate" per user role on specific product ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871587/tax-class-zero-rate-per-user-role-on-specific-product-ids/40893064#40893064)*

But there is no way and this is not the option. I can't make it work to inactivate Tax only for tours and hotels.

I need some help, to understand how I can achieve disabling taxes only for tours and hotels within my theme in WooCommerce.

---

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

I am using this little peace code to output my custom product types from cart, where I have the 3 different kinds of products types:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table','output_cart_raw_data');
function output_cart_raw_data(){
    $count = 0;
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item){
    $count++;
    echo 'Product ' . $count . ' has a post type of: ' . $cart_item['st_booking_data']['st_booking_post_type'] . '<br>;
}
}
```

It outputs in my cart page this (the product types used):

```
Product 1 has a post type of: st_tours
Product 2 has a post type of: st_hotel
Product 3 has a post type of: st_activity
```

How can I get `'Zero Tax'` activated for `st_tours` and `st_activity` product types?

Thanks

Comment: template this https://themeforest.net/item/traveler-traveltourbooking-wordpress-theme/10822683

Comment: @LoicTheAztec It is a reservation system, in the configuration of woocommerce active the tax for everything, the theme does not have the function to disable tax on tours and activities, when a booking is made to a tour, the theme creates a woocommerce product, but places The tax, I need to remove the tax for only tours and activities

Comment: @LoicTheAztec My English is not good, can I send you the theme? And you help me?  Thank very much edit my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your question last update, this is very easy... Your products have a custom booking type. You have 3 kinds of booking types and you want to get the "Zero Tax" rate for all product types except 'st_hotel' product type.

So the code is going to be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1, 2 );
function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Iterating through each cart items
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item){

        if($product->id == $cart_item['product_id']){
            $booking_post_type = $cart_item['st_booking_data']['st_booking_post_type'];
            break;
        }
        $count++;
        echo 'Product ' . $count . ' has a post type of: ' .$cart_item['st_booking_data']['st_booking_post_type']. '<br>;
    }

    // If the booking post type is different than 'st_hotel', the "Zero Tax" rate is applied
    if( 'st_hotel' != $booking_post_type ){
        $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';
    }

    return $tax_class;

}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works…

---

error in the code

Comment: Thank very much! you are great.... also error 500 When I add the code in functions.php

Comment: I have corrected it was a typo error… a missing `;` at the end of `$product_type = $cart_item['st_booking_data']['st_booking_post_type'];` … sorry :)